# zsh: permission denied

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

I m a beginner with terminal I don't know why every time I try to open a directory from the terminal this pops up. Even I gave full disk access to the terminal then also this pops up. [permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odV2o.jpg)

Comment: The first "word" on the command line is the name of the command you want to execute (something like `pwd`, `ls`, `open`, etc). Directories are not commands; you can't execute them. You probably want something like `cd /Users/yu` (to change your working directory to `/Users/yu`) or `ls /Users/yu` (to list the contents of `/Users/yu`) or maybe `open /Users/yu` (to open the directory in the Finder).

Comment: @Shivesh : What do you mind by _opening a directory_? Do you want to start the Finder on this directory?

Comment: @Shivesh : From the screenshot, I see only that you tried plenty of meaningless commands, but since I don't know what you want to achieve, it is hard to advise you here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able enter dirs without typing `cd`, you need to add this to your `.zshrc` file:

```
setopt autocd
```

Also, if you want to insert the value of a parameter – such as `$PWD` or `$HOME` – you need to prefix its name with a `$`, like I just did. The `$` tells the shell to substitute the value of the parameter, instead of treating whatever you typed as plain text (unless substituted by a global alias).

Comment: please click on Permission denied viewing the image

Comment: @Shivesh Yes, I looked at your image, and this is my answer. Please try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Running BigSur on Mac... Make sure you're in the right directory (where your file is located) say your file is on Documents type:

```
cd Documents
```